# Entity storing it's status as a FK to a status table. Can i update the FK once the status changes?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've designed a table 'A' in which it's current status is one property that is also one FK to a table 'B' that contains statuses. Somewhere along the application cycle the status of the entities presented in the table 'A' will change, and i'm wondering if i can just update the FK collumn with the new status, that obviously is also contained in table 'B'.

It seems pretty normal to me, but as i haven't found a single post/article/question in all my searching i'm not sure wether it is acceptable or completely wrong.

Comment: So you'd change the code in table B and all the instances in table A of that code would be changed, too?  It sounds like you want [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: That's not how I read the question @BaconBits.  I think he's asking if he can update the value of the FK column in Table A to another valid value of the PK of TableB, and the answer is yes, why not?

Comment: @TabAlleman You might be right.  I think I got turned around in the ambiguity of the example.

Comment: it was exactly what @TabAlleman said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As table A has the foreign key to table B you can simply update the value on table A to a new value in table B.

For example, you have
table A: id, name, status_id (foreign key)
table B: id, status_name

in table B you have:

```
1, "started"
2, "stopped"
3, "suspended"
```

in table A you have:

```
1, "application_A", 1
2, "application_B", 1
```

If you want to stop application_A, simply update the value in column `status_id` to 2.

It's the other way round that's difficult: if for some (god forsaken) reason you would have to update the `id` from 2 to 4 in the table B for the row where status_name is "stopped" - only then you would have to dig out `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or similar measures.

Comment: Thanks, i know the question is pretty 'idiot' but besides associative tables that's something i've never done in my 4~5 years working as a programmer, so altough i knew all along that it would work i was not sure if was the right thing to do.